# Using ajax to print "testing" to the screen when you click a label

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying use ajax to print "testing" to the screen when you click a label, but it's not working for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

**test.php**

```
<style>
#output {
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
<label value='show time' onclick="ajaxFunc('test1.php', 'output')"> Click me </label>
<div id='output'></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function ajaxFunc(gotoUrl, output) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: gotoUrl,
    error: function(xhr, status, error){
      alert(error);
    },
    success: function(data) {
      document.getElementById( output ).innerHTML = data;
    } //end of success:function(data)
  }); //end of $.ajax

</script>
```

**test1.php**

```
<?php
echo "testing";
?>
```

Comment: Not an answer, but helpful in such situations: if you're using Chrome (highly suggest you do, for development), press F12. That will bring up Development Tools (it's in most browsers today). There you will find "Console" tab, or anywhere, look for a "Console". In this situation, in that console you would've seen an error message, that would be very self-explanatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be getting an

> Unexpected end of input

error as you have not closed the brace of your function.

Use this,

```
function ajaxFunc(gotoUrl, output) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: gotoUrl,
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        },
        success: function(data) {
                document.getElementById(output).innerHTML = data;
            } //end of success:function(data)
    });
}
```

Notice how the function has been closed with the `}`.

**Additional Information**

Consistency is the key, you are using single and double quotes in your HTML because of the nested event listener, you should attach your listeners in the [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Use *F12* when using Chrome to access the console to see if any errors have occurred. Check [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) very helpful link out to find out how to open the console in other browsers.

Comment: if you have a phpini can you show me the error codes you use?

Comment: PHPINI is different to the console. Console shows you JavaScript errors.

Comment: I just want the necessary errors to show up and not errors like, you have declare a variable or anything like that.

Comment: @jessica The console will only show "necessary" errors. If you see an error in your Javascript console, something broke.

Comment: @jessica Pop it open and find out ;) (spoiler alert: yes)